# Change width of dropdown menu of v-combobox

Tags: css, vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make a multiple search filter like the one in Gitlab dashboard.

[image: Gitlab search]

For that purpose, i'm using Vuetify v-combobox like so :

```
    <v-combobox
        id="mycombo"
        v-model="model"
        :items="items"
        multiple
        small-chips
    >
        <template v-slot:item="{ index, item }" >     
            <v-icon>
                {{item.icon}}
            </v-icon>
            <span>
                {{ item.text }}
            </span>                 
        </template>
    </v-combobox>
```

The first obstacle I encounter is changing the width of the dropdown. When I inspect in the browser I see some element style :

```
    <div class="v-menu__content theme--light menuable__content__active v-autocomplete__content" style="max-height: 304px; min-width: 1543px; top: 193px; left: 308px; transform-origin: left top; z-index: 8;">
```

If I modify the min-width parameter directly in the inspector, I can successfully change the width of the dropdown.

My question is how can I do the same thing in code (preferably in the scoped CSS) ?

I tried :

- Adding a class to a template v-slot:item -> not possible
- Changing style of v-autocomplete content since v-combobox is a child of v-autocomplete :

```
    .v-menu__content .menuable__content__active .v-autocomplete__content {
        min-width: 250px !important;
    }
```

- I read about deep styling but could not understand how to use it in this case

What is the general process for styling a vue component ?

Thanks for reading, hava g'day mates !

Comment: how about wrap a div around your template and try to give it a class

Comment: other solution is the `::v-deep` modifier, getting deep into v-components without removing `scoped`

Comment: Did not think of the div wrapping, unfortunately, it does not seems to work : ```'v-slot' directive must be owned by a custom element, but 'div' is not.```. Can u explain a little more about the ```::v-deep``` modifier, with an example maybe, can't wrap me head around it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use :menu-props for your styles:

```
 <v-combobox
     id="mycombo"
     v-model="model"
     :items="items"
     multiple
     small-chips
     :menu-props="{ minWidth: '250', maxHeight: '600' }"
 >
   <template v-slot:item="{ index, item }">
     <v-icon>
       {{ item.icon }}
     </v-icon>
     <span>
        {{ item.text }}
     </span>
   </template>
 </v-combobox>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Zero, menu-props did the trick. I accept your answer as solution ! List of all props : [#props](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-menu/#props)